Cannot render/import lineicons-react package as expected using Next.JS framework
Expecting the LineIcons component to render in the tsx component as per the documentation, but it is not rendering. The LineIcons component is imported from the lineicons-react package. I am using next.js framework.
The documentation advises to import the LineIcons component as follows:
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import LineIcon from "lineicons-react";

function App() {
  return <LineIcon name="spinner" />;
}

Error Message
Preview page reads:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `PersonalProjects`.

Messages:
'LineIcon' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type 'typeof import("c:/Users/lmcre/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/lauriecrean_nextjs/node_modules/lineicons-react/dist/types/index")' is not a valid JSX element type.

Terminal:
 ✓ Compiled /_not-found in 266ms (1374 modules)
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at PersonalProjects
    at Lazy
    at div
    [...]

debugging steps part A

Check the import statement for the LineIcon component. The import statement is correct.
Check npm install lineicons-react in the terminal. The lineicons-react package is installed.
Check the LineIcon component in the node_modules folder. The LineIcon component is present in the node_modules folder.
remove the .next folder and restart the server. The LineIcon component is still not rendering.
create a new tsx file and import the LineIcon component. The LineIcon component renders not as expected.

TestLineIcon.tsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LineIcon from 'lineicons-react';

const TestLineIcon = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Testing LineIcon</h2>
            <LineIcon name="spinner" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default TestLineIcon;

preview
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined

terminal
PS C:\Users\lmcre\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\lauriecrean_nextjs> npm run dev

> nextjs@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.3
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000

 ✓ Starting...
 ✓ Ready in 2.2s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ✓ Compiled / in 4.4s (1163 modules)
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
 ⨯ Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "2342878422"
 ⨯ Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "2342878422"
 GET / 500 in 4859ms
 ✓ Compiled in 485ms (556 modules)
 ○ Compiling /favicon.ico ...
 ✓ Compiled /favicon.ico in 2.6s (606 modules)
 GET /favicon.ico 200 in 2720ms

problems:
'LineIcon' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type 'typeof import("c:/Users/lmcre/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/lauriecrean_nextjs/node_modules/lineicons-react/dist/types/index")' is not a valid JSX element type.

debugging steps Part B:

checked version installed with npm list: it is lineicons-react@1.0.5
check node_modules/lineicons-react/dist/types/index.d.ts for the LineIcon component. The LineIcon component is present in the index.d.ts file in the first line as export { default as LineIcon } from "./LineIcon";
use dynamic import to import the LineIcon component. The terminal reads no errors, however, the LineIcon component is still not rendering and preview is revealing an error message.

TestLineIcon.tsx
"use client"

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

// Dynamically import LineIcon to avoid server-side rendering issues. Currently leading to problem message...
const LineIcon = dynamic(() => import('lineicons-react').then((mod) => mod.default), { ssr: false });


const TestLineIcon = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Testing LineIcon</h2>
            <LineIcon name="spinner" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default TestLineIcon;

problems
Argument of type '() => Promise<typeof import("c:/Users/lmcre/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/lauriecrean_nextjs/node_modules/lineicons-react/dist/types/index")>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamicOptions<{}> | Loader<{}>'.
  Type '() => Promise<typeof import("c:/Users/lmcre/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/lauriecrean_nextjs/node_modules/lineicons-react/dist/types/index")>' is not assignable to type '() => LoaderComponent<{}>'.
    Type 'Promise<typeof import("c:/Users/lmcre/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/lauriecrean_nextjs/node_modules/lineicons-react/dist/types/index")>' is not assignable to type 'LoaderComponent<{}>'.
      Type 'typeof import("c:/Users/lmcre/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/lauriecrean_nextjs/node_modules/lineicons-react/dist/types/index")' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}> | ComponentModule<{}>'.


Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

preview:
Error: Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: undefined. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function.

terminal message seems ok now:
PS C:\Users\lmcre\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\lauriecrean_nextjs> npm run dev

> nextjs@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.3
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000

 ✓ Starting...
 ✓ Ready in 2.2s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ✓ Compiled / in 4.2s (1176 modules)
 GET / 200 in 4649ms
 ✓ Compiled in 403ms (563 modules)
 ○ Compiling /favicon.ico ...
 ✓ Compiled /favicon.ico in 2.7s (612 modules)
 GET /favicon.ico 200 in 2775ms

